# How can I change a row to be text instead of a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am copying a row of phone numbers that are text strings from Excel to Google Sheets.

The phone numbers change from text to formulas when pasted and return `#ERROR!`

For example, the text `+49 4942 12345678` from Excel becomes the formula `=+49 4942 12345678` when pasted into Sheets and returns `#ERROR!`.

I want to remove the equals sign `=`.  How can I format the row to show the phone numbers as text again?

Answer (score 1):

### Replace equals sign `=` with single quote `'`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> will bring up the **"Find and Replace"** dialog.

In the sample image below I configured the range as the entire column G.  You would enter the row or column or even individual cells that are affected as the case may be.

You must select **"also search within formulas"** or it will ignore the affected cells.

[image: find and replace dialog box]